# Derivatives question on partial derivatives

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, exponential-function, partial-derivative

If $z=f(x,y)$ and $x=e^u \cos v$, $y=e^u \sin v$ then show that 
$y \frac{dz}{du} + x \frac{dz}{dv} = e^{2u} \frac{dz}{dy}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\ \mbox{ and }\ \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v},$$
where
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=e^u\cos(v)\ ,\quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=e^u\sin(v)$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=-e^u\sin(v)\ ,\quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=e^u\cos(v)$$
Such that
$$y\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}+x\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=e^u\sin(v)\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}e^u\cos(v)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}e^u\sin(v)\right)$$
$$+e^u\cos(v)\left(-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}e^u\sin(v)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}e^u\cos(v)\right)$$
$$=e^{2u}\sin(v)\cos(v)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-e^{2u}\sin(v)\cos(v)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+e^{2u}\sin^2(v)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+e^{2u}\cos^2(v)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
$$=e^{2u}\bigg[\sin^2(v)+\cos^2(v)\bigg]\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=e^{2u}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Thank you. Perfectly done.

Comment: You're welcome :) Small tip: I didn't see why $y\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}+x\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=e^{2u}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ immediately, I just started writing out each term and figured it'll be clear along the way. That is usually the way to approach these things, just start writing it out, until things drop out.

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind.